getting com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
`
String dbURI = "mongodb://host:password@ip:port/?authSource=admin&tlsCAFile=ca.crt&tlsCertificateKeyFile=client.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFilePassword=password";
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));

        MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
                .writeConcern(WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED)
                .readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
                .minConnectionsPerHost(10)
                .serverSelectionTimeout(2_000)
                .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);

        mongo = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(dbURI, builder));`

Getting com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
Exception, even though i have ca.crt and client.pem file in the path
I am able to connect to mongodb both in mongo compass and from terminal, but not from java app.
please help me with it

Does this answer your question? Mongo X509 tls connection options
